# call bat file in new windows from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to launch a bat file in new window/independent instance from within powershell.

the bat file will take a computername from powershell
e.g.

```
mybat.bat $thiscomputer
```

Ive tried

```
start mybat.bat $thiscomputer
start "cmd /c" mybat.bat $thiscomputer
start /k mybat.bat $thiscomputer
start-process mybat.bat $thiscomputer
```

ordinarily the bat does run but stays within the powershell script.

I need the powershell script to launch the bat in anew window and loop back to the beginning.

Thanks

Confuseis

Answer (score 6):

`Start-Process` runs console programs in a new window by default.  The only problem with your syntax is that you need to use the `-ArgumentList` parameter to pass arguments to the program you've started.  PowerShell doesn't let you simply list them after the program name.

```
PS> Start-Process $env:comspec -ArgumentList "mybat.bat $thiscomputer"
```

or, in shorter form,

```
PS> start mybat.bat -a $thiscomputer
```

`-ArgumentList` only takes one string, so if you have multiple arguments to pass, then you need to put them all into one string before passing to `Start-Process`.